# How to use rebootWipeUserData() from an application in AOSP?

Tags: java, android, android-source

I have been trying to factory reset the android if user presses and holds a specific key for 5 or more seconds. I'm able to receive the KeyEvent and after 5 seconds lapses, I'm trying to do factory reset by referring [this link from android developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/RecoverySystem#rebootWipeUserData(android.content.Context)). Even though I have declared reboot permission in my manifest **uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT"**, I'm facing SecurityException.
I got an instance from the RECOVERY_SERVICE and calling rebootWipeUserData(context)

Give me some inputs on how can I proceed with this further.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting security exception because you are not allowed to factory reset

Only  a device administrator is allowed to do that. Please follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin) to implement a device administration code.

If you face any issues while implementing feel free to ask

Or another solution could be that if your application is system app then it could do what you have implemented so far but i have not tried it

Comment: Thanks Mushahid.
I shall give it a try and get back to you